# Can you provide loss_weights when using add_loss?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, tensorflow2.0, loss-function

In tensorflow 2, when using multiple losses added with `model.add_loss`, when doing `model.compile`, can you pass `loss_weights` argument to make the model loss a weighted sum of the losses added?

Something like this:

```py
model.add_loss(loss_1)
model.add_loss(loss_2)
model.compile(loss_weights=[1, 0.5], optimizer='adam')
```

Comment: Yes, either a list or a dictionary. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#compile

Comment: I assume so, I can't find sources for that. Both ways add losses, you just have to make sure to compile the model after you add the loss. The best way to verify it would be to have a converging loss and a diverging loss. Modifying (inverting) the weights you should have different results.. (e.g. loss_weights=[1, 0] and [0, 1])

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the documentation of compile, I have read it but it is not clear to me whether loss_weights can apply to losses added with add_loss or if it only applies to losses given directly to compile. Do you have any source confirming this?

Comment: Could do the check and post an answer please? I can't run any tensorflow code for now as I have some training already running. I'll accept it if it works.

Comment: I will test it the next days